# Set up two-way ssl authentication for web site

Tags: php, authentication, ssl, apache2

I would like to implement *two-way ssl authentication* for a web site. I couldn't find a lot of documentation about this....

What I want is something similar to what StartSSL has:

- Creating a client certificate and install it on the browser (registration)
- Check for the ssl client certificate when trying to access some pages (login)

I found this tutorial: https://www.scriptjunkie.us/2013/11/adding-easy-ssl-client-authentication-to-any-webapp/ , and I followed it step by step....

This is the website where I'm experimenting: https://cert.devpgsv.com/getacert.php

(The code of "getacert.php" is here: https://cert.devpgsv.com/code.php )

(I have enabled access to [.htaccess](https://cert.devpgsv.com/.htaccess) file in case it is useful)

The main problem I have right now is: when trying to generate the certificate, the browser displays:

```
El servidor a devuelto un certificado de cliente no valido. Error 207 (net:::ERR_CERT_INVALID)
```

The error displays in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox......

Info: I useApache2 installed on a Debian.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

In newer versions of php the value I was looking for was not present by default. It as only there when certain conditions were met...

I had to add `SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars` in my .htaccess
Then I changd the permissions of the folders where I was running the command so that "www-data" could geenrate the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is a rather simple "undefined index" warning that you get in PHP when attempting to access a non-existing array key. Check if the key exists using `if (array_key_exists('SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN', $_SERVER))` before checking it's value.

Comment: I know that it doesn't exist. What I don't know is why. 
I need that value, so it should be there....

If I check if the key exist and it fails... then how do I get what is supposed to be in SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN?

Comment: Are you actually sending the certificate? Because if not, it will not exist. I cannot tell you how the certificate info is ending up in $_SERVER, since I do not have experience with this method of client authentication.